# Add noise (random values) to data

Tags: random

I have a data set(x,y,z) corresponding to a hemisphere, to which I want to add some controlled noise (random values) to make the x,y,z values diverge.

> data = Flatten[  Table[{i, j, i^2 + j^2}, {i, -10, 10, 1}, {j, -10, 10, 1}], 1]

The above is a 3 coordinate set (x,y,z) values for a hemisphere. How do I add random noise to it?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "to make the x,y,z values diverge."?

Comment: `Flatten[
   Table[{i, j, i^2 + j^2 + RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {i, -10, 10, 
     1}, {j, -10, 10, 1}], 1];`?

Comment: Ahh sorry.. the above code gives me 3 points =  (x,y,z) and I want to add noise to x,y,z, that is some random values (range 0 - 5) to x,y,z

Comment: maybe a function that add some random values to each point?

Comment: `noisydata = # + RandomReal[5, 3] & /@ data;`?

Comment: Yea..Kguler, that does it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @belisarius, I just realised you made some changes to the code you quoted above. This works fine too. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful because @kguler's and mine aren't equivalent. He is "noising" the three coordinates, while I was adding noise just to `z`

Comment: And ... I haven't edited my comment!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 data = Flatten[Table[{i, j, i^2 + j^2}, {i, -10, 10, 1}, {j, -10, 10, 1}], 1];
 noisydata = # + RandomReal[5, 3] & /@ data;
 Row[{ListPlot3D[data, ImageSize -> 300, BoxRatios -> 1],
   ListPlot3D[noisydata, ImageSize -> 300, BoxRatios -> 1]}]
```

[image]