# How do I generate a table of data points from a function and add random noise?

Tags: plotting, functions

I am trying to generate a table of data for the function:

```
f(x) := (Sin[2 Pi t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 Pi t] + (1/10) Sin[8 Pi t])
Table[Plot[f[t], {t, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> {150, 150}], {t, -5, 5}]
```

I believe I plotted it correctly by using this syntax tp define the function and
make the plot, but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

Also, I want to add random noise,but I do not know how.

Comment: This might get you started: `foo = Interpolation@Table[{x, RandomReal[{-0.2,0.2}]}, {x, -5, 5, 0.01}]; Plot[
 Sin[x] + foo[x], {x, -5, 5}]`

Comment: Do you mean like the variable `data` in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-multi-peak-fitting/26357#26357)?

Answer (score 3):

This post is a partial answer, directed at your question about your syntax, which is incorrect as posted.

In *Mathematica*, a function function of one variable `t` is defined with the syntax `f[t_] := ...`, not `f(t) = ...`. Note the square brackets `[ ]` and the underscore `_` after the the `t` which identifies `t` as a variable.

Further, I don't understand why you introduced `Table` when making your plot. Do you really want 11 copies of the plot? Because that's what your `Table` expression will deliver.

Here is the correct syntax for what I think you really want:

```
f[t_] := (Sin[2 Pi t]) (1 + (1/5) Sin[6 Pi t] + (1/10) Sin[8 Pi t])

Plot[f[t], {t, -5, 5}, ImageSize -> {150, 150}]
```

which will produce the Output

[image: plot.png]

The part of your question concerning randomizing your data has been answered before in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18132/add-noise-random-values-to-data).

Answer (score 2):

It is not clearly explained in your post, what should be the result. I can only guess, that you would like to get the function (the one you posted) modified by some noise.

Here the function noisedSignal[] is introduced. Check Menu/Help/tutorial/DefiningFunctions. It contains your signal modified by the noise. The latter is represented by RandomReal. Check Menu/Help/RandomReal to get more information. noisedSignal makes a table out of your function. Its terms have the form {t, signal}. It depends upon the variables a, the limit of the noise amplitude, and delta - the interval between the time values in the table. Check Menu/Help/Table. Evaluate this:

```
  noisedSignal[a_, \[Delta]_] :=
      Table[{t, 
        Sin[2 Pi t]*(1 + (1/5) Sin[6 Pi t] + (1/10) Sin[8 Pi t]) + 
         RandomReal[{-a, a}]}, {t, -5, 5, \[Delta]}];
```

Evaluate also the following and play with the parameter a by moving the slider:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[noisedSignal[a, 0.001], 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["t", 14, Italic], Style["Signal", 14]}], {a, 
  0.1, 1}]
```

Have fun.

Comment: The `RandomReal[{-a, a}]` portion can of course be changed, if one wants noise that is not uniformly distributed. If one wants, say, Gaussian noise, what's needed is something like `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]`, or replace the `0` and `1` there with the desired mean and standard deviation, respectively.